ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'question'}
from langchain.llms import GooglePalm
from langchain.utilities import SQLDatabase
from langchain_experimental.sql import SQLDatabaseChain
from langchain.prompts import SemanticSimilarityExampleSelector
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.chains.sql_database.prompt import PROMPT_SUFFIX, _mysql_prompt
from langchain import PromptTemplate
from example import example
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.embeddings import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
    
def get_db_chain():
    #create connection with db
    db_user = ""
    db_password = ""
    db_host = ""
    db_name = ""

    db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(
        f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}/{db_name}",
        sample_rows_in_table_info=3,
    )
    #print(db.table_info)

    llm = GooglePalm(google_api_key='', temperature=0.1)

    embeddings = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
    to_vectorize = [" ".join(example.values()) for example in example]
    vectorstore = FAISS.from_texts(to_vectorize, embedding=embeddings)

    example_selector = SemanticSimilarityExampleSelector(
        vectorstore=vectorstore, 
        k=2
    )

    mysql_prompt = '''Given an input question, first create a syntactically correct MSSQL SERVER query to run based on the database schema, 
    then look at the results of the query and return the answer.Use the following format:

    Question:{question}
    SQLQuery: Query to run with no pre-amble
    SQLResult: Result of the SQLQuery
    Answer: Final answer here

    No pre-amble
    '''

    prompt_template = PromptTemplate(
        example_selector=example_selector,
        suffix=PROMPT_SUFFIX,
        template=mysql_prompt,
        input_variables=["question"],
    )
    
    chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm, db, verbose=True, prompt=prompt_template)

    return chain

chain = get_db_chain()
question = 'ID: dongwook@naver.com, How long did you use your cell phone yesterday?'

response = chain.run(question)    # ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'question'}
#response = chain.run({'question' : question})    # ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'query'}
#response = chain.run({'question' : question, 'query':question})    # ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'question'}
#response = chain(question)    # ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'question'}
#response = chain({'question' : question})    # ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'query'}
#response = chain({'question' : question, 'query': question})    # ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'question'}


An error occurs in the chain.run part. It says there is no question, so if I put in a question, there is no question, and if I put in a question, there is no question again.
I keep looking for it by referring to Google's various posts, but I don't know how to do it.
But it works except for the prompt part in Chain.
I've added my attempts as an annotation to the code.

Please post the full error message and traceback in the question.
